# Combine elements in list of strings by indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, reshape

I have a list of string like this

```
 list1 =  ["['First Standard', 'First Flex', 'Business Standard']", "
    ['P,F', 'A', 'C,D,F,G']"]
```

and I'd like to reformat it to look like this:

```
 list2 = ["['First Standard','P','F']", "['First Flex','A']", "['Business 
  Standard','C','D','F','G']"]
```

Comment: Great! Do you have a question?

Comment: Is there a point earlier in the code where you can use the list objects, instead of repr() format?

Comment: there is no code, just weirdly formatted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process parallel collections of related data the `zip` function is useful.

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
zip(a,b)
> [(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]
```

Also you can get `ast.literal_eval` to get a list from those strings.

```
ast.literal_eval("[1,2,3]")
> [1,2,3]
```

Applying this to your case:

```
data = ["['First Standard', 'First Flex', 'Business Standard']", "['P,F', 'A', 'C,D,F,G']"]
result = [[x] + y.split(",") for (x,y) in zip(ast.literal_eval(data[0]),ast.literal_eval(data[1]))]
```

## EDIT:

You could also treat this data as valid json and use this.

```
import json
result = [[x] + y.split(",") for (x,y) in zip(json.loads(data[0]),json.loads(data[1]))]
```

Comment: He has strings not list objects.

Comment: BTW, be VERY careful with this, make sure you can trust your data source. Even better, try to parse your data in some other way, I used eval here for simpicity but this is vulnerable to code injection.

Comment: Did you read the question? Your answer is not relevant to this case.

Comment: I would highly recommend not using eval.

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval` instead of raw `eval`.

Comment: @AlexHall Thanks, I didn't knew about it. Updated my answer and learned something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the eval expression (which I would strongly reccomend for security reasons) you can do it with a regex. As noted in the comments, you will need to change this if your data contains nested single quotes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

start_list = [
"['First Standard', 'First Flex', 'Business Standard']",
"['P,F', 'A', 'C,D,F,G']"
]

pattern = "'(.*?)'"

new_list = []
for stringsInList in start_list:
    words = re.findall(pattern, stringsInList)
    new_list.append(words)


final = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(new_list[0], new_list[1])]
print(final) 
#[('First Standard', 'P,F'), ('First Flex', 'A'), ('Business Standard', 'C,D,F,G')]
```

***Edit*** - Slightly more condensed

```
start_list = [
"['First Standard', 'First Flex', 'Business Standard']",
"['P,F', 'A', 'C,D,F,G']"
]

new_list = [re.findall("'(.*?)'", x) for x in start_list]
final = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(new_list[0], new_list[1])]

print(final)
```

Comment: Until the string contains single quotes.

Comment: You can just adjust the pattern, I'm only going on what he's given.